# SQL "not in" syntax and nested SELECT in Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I recently used Entity Framework. For elementary CRUD operations, I have no problems, but for more complicated queries, I do not know how to do these.

For example: how to write a nested select? How to use the `NOT IN` operator?

The query that I want to write is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM course
WHERE idCourse NOT IN (SELECT idCourse 
                       FROM reservation 
                       WHERE idStudent = 'value');
```

I do not know where to start. Could you please give me some advice?

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: I would recommend this tutorial for anything about `EntityFramework`: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/Querying-with-EDM.aspx .

Answer (score 1):

If I do not misunderstood your question, you want to know how to write the question's query as `LINQ-to-Entity` query.

Examples could be:

```
var courses = context.Courses
    .Where(c => c.Reservations.All(r => r.idStudent != "value"))
    .Select(c => c);

// with eager loading
var courses = (from c in context.Courses.Include(c => c.Reservations)
               where c.Reservations.All(r => r.idStudent != "value")
               select c).ToArray();

var courses = (from c in context.Courses
               join r in context.Reservations on c.idCourse equals r.idCourse
               where r => r.idStudent != "value"
               select c).ToArray();
```

The `Contains()` is equivalent to `EXIST IN` in a query. Well, 1st and 2nd nearly the same. Only difference is the `Include` method to show how you could *eager load* data.
In the 3rd query I use the join key word to do a join operation - equivalent to an `INNER JOIN`. The result will contain only records where a relation between a course and a reservation exists and the searched student ID is referenced in the reservation.

If you should not use LINQ for your querys, you should take a look. It's a perfect way to decouple your data access layer from persistence layer and you could test all your queries in code too.

[Here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/Querying-with-EDM.aspx) you could get a very good entry into the subject.

EDIT:
Modified example code to fit `NOT IN`.

Comment: Careful, OP asked for `NOT IN`. Your code will return `courses` where a `reservation` contains the `idstudent` "value", which is contrary to the question. Will remove the downvote whenever the edit is made.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, upvoted for great explanations

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble executing complex queries with LINQ, you can also execute raw SQL queries. They are easy and faster than linq queries.

Here is an example in c#

```
var list = dc.Database.SqlQuery<YourCourceClass>(@"SELECT * 
FROM course
WHERE idCourse NOT IN(SELECT idCourse
                       FROM reservation
                       WHERE idStudent = 'value');").ToList();
```